# How to specify an image property for a MIDI endpoint?

Tags: ios, coremidi

I have an application that exposes a virtual MIDI output. How do I give the `MIDIPortRef` an image using `kMIDIPropertyImage`?

The value given is supposed to be an URL to an image file as specified here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremidi/kmidipropertyimage

There are apps like Midiflow that give you a listing of all available input/output virtual MIDI ports and include an icon for the host app. I'm assuming this is the mechanism at play here, but would love to be enlightened.

Answer (score 0):

With [MIDIObjectSetStringProperty](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremidi/1495173-midiobjectsetstringproperty?language=objc)

Comment: What is the format of the string? What image formats does it support and does it need to be encoded somehow? If it's not actual image data, what kind of content should it refer to?

Comment: Most formats, e.g. png, jpg. maximum size is 128x128. A URL to a bundle resource will work